# How can I remove some content from Iframe?

Tags: html

```
<iframe id="sample_test" src="http://localhost:3000/tests/384" seamless="seamless" width="100%" height="1150px" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

This frame renders also `#current_user_bar`, which this way is displayed twice: from layout, and from frame.

How can I make it invisible in frame(but visible else content of the frame)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `$("#sample_test").contents().find("#current_user_bar").hide();`

Comment: Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/contents/). On that page check "Change the background colour of links inside of an iframe."